# FCM delivery receipts behavior

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I set the `delivery_receipt_requested` parameter in the message I send, to request delivery receipts.

Are delivery receipt always sent, or does the framework behave differently if the app is running background or foreground?

The documentation tackles the question, but do not explicitly tells if the app behaves the same way or not. I would like to be sure I am not missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why it doesn't **explicitly** say anything about whether it is received when your client app is in foreground or background is because regardless of it, it is technically considered as **received** by the device, which is what is explicitly mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#receipts):

> For Android and Chrome client apps, you can get delivery receipts (sent from CCS to your app server) **when a device confirms that it received a message sent by CCS**.

The behavior I think that you should be wary of is when receiving duplicate receipts when the connection is poor between the CSS and the device:

> If the connection between CCS and the device is poor, **GCM may send multiple, duplicate delivery receipts**. You can safely ignore such duplicates.

Other than that, pretty sure there's no other difference what the status of the client app is when the message is received.